# Separate fields array with container in theme options ( Carbon Fields )

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, containers, custom-fields, carbon-fields

Is it possible to separate those two add_fields() and wrap each other in container with a title so they look nicer in theme options?

```
add_action( 'carbon_fields_register_fields', 'crb_attach_theme_options' );
function crb_attach_theme_options() {
    Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Theme Options' ) )
        ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('text', 'tel_nmbr', 'Telephone number'),
            Field::make('text', 'whatsapp_nmbr', 'WhatsApp number'),
            Field::make('text', 'viber_nmbr', 'WhatsApp number'),
            Field::make('text', 'telegram_nmbr', 'Telegram number'),
        ))
        ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('textarea', 'ga_field', 'Google Analytics code')
                ->set_rows(4),
            Field::make('textarea', 'banners_field', 'Banners code')
                ->set_rows(4)
        ));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it! just have to put the field "Separator" in between.

```
Field::make( 'separator', 'crb_separator', __( 'Social' ) )
```